# How to quickly label photos of people on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, photos.app

I want to take pictures of people I meet and add their name to the picture quickly and easily so I can move to the next person right away. Quick and easy is the key!

Comment: Please let us know the version of iOS you are using and if you want to accomplish your task using Apple's built-in tools or using a third party app.